# I am writing a program to find number of 3's in factorial of a given number. The input from the user is the number

Tags: java

I am using this logic. Suppose I have to find number of 3's in 10!. Then[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSfbw.jpg)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class testing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int temp=0,a;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number ");
        int n = obj.nextInt();
        int i=1;
        while(n<(Math.pow(3,i)))
        {
            a= n/(int)(Math.pow(3,i));
            temp=temp+a;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Answer: " +temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change < to > in  if condition as

   ```
      n >(Math.pow(3,i))
   ```
2. or use below code which calculates pow only once

   ```
   int temp = 0, a;
   Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the number ");
   int n = obj.nextInt();
   int i = 1;
   while (true) {
       int pow = (int) Math.pow(3, i);
       if (pow > n) {
           break;
       } else {
           temp = temp + n / pow;
       }

       i++;
   }
   System.out.println("Answer: " + temp);
   ```